# $u_{1},...,u_{n}\in V$ L.I.. Then for any $v_{1},...,v_{n}\in V$, $\exists$ infinitely $\alpha$ s.t. $u_{1}+\alpha v_{1},...,u_{n}+\alpha v_{n}$ L.I..

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $u_{1},...,u_{n}\in V$ are linearly independent. Prove that for any $v_{1},...,v_{n}\in V$, $u_{1}+\alpha v_{1},...,u_{n}+\alpha v_{n}$ are linearly independent for all but finitely many values of $\alpha\in F$.

I know that if $v_{1},...,v_{n}\in V$ are linearly dependent and there exist $\beta\in F$ such that $u_{1}+\beta v_{1},...,u_{n}+\beta v_{n}$ are linearly dependent, then there are infintely many values to make that set linearly dependent. But I have no idea if $v_{1},...,v_{n}\in V$ are linearly independent, Can someone give me some advise? Thanks!

Comment: It should suffice to solve this when $\dim V = n$ and in particular solve the special case of $ V = \mathbb F^n$.  The "all but finitely many $\alpha$" strongly suggests a polynomial identity, where one in particular comes to mind.  What progress can you make with this?

Comment: Elaborating on the previous hint: if $\dim V=n$ let $D:V^n\to F$ be a determinant function on $V$ and consider the polynomial $$f(\alpha)=D(u_1+\alpha v_1,\ldots,u_n+\alpha v_n)$$ What can you say about the finitely many roots of $f$?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Because $f(\alpha)$ is polynomial and $f(0)\neq 0$ implies $f$ is not zero function, $f(\alpha)$ has only finitely many roots, which are the values of $\alpha$ that make the set linearly dependent.